# Why are my multiple devise_for calls for OmniAuth not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

## Short version

When using dynamic route segments with OmniAuth the official recommendation of Devise is to use multiple calls of `devise_for`: ([Source](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/5d5636f03ac19e8188d99c044d4b5e90124313af/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb#L424))

```rb
devise_for :users, only: :omniauth_callbacks, controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks' }

scope '/(:locale)', locale: /ru|en/ do
  devise_for :users, skip: :omniauth_callbacks
end
```

But for me this simply doesn't work, because the settings from the first `devise_for` call are lost (i.e. the overridden controller is gone) and only the configuration from the second call is kept.

**What am I missing here?**

In my opinion it cannot work ever, because each and every `devise_for` call replaces the previous mapping and all of its settings.

On the other hand it **is** the officially documented way and there is some praise about this solution in the Devise issue tracker.

## More details

### Devise source code

This is how the code looks like: ([Source](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/5d5636f03ac19e8188d99c044d4b5e90124313af/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb#L243))

```rb
def devise_for(*resources)
  # ...
  resources.each do |resource|
    mapping = Devise.add_mapping(resource, options)
    # ...
  end
  #...
end
```

And the code for `add_mapping`: ([Source](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/5d5636f03ac19e8188d99c044d4b5e90124313af/lib/devise.rb#L345))

```rb
def self.add_mapping(resource, options)
  mapping = Devise::Mapping.new(resource, options)
  @@mappings[mapping.name] = mapping
  # ...
end
```

As you can see any previous mapping and its configuration is replaced with the new one.
According to git blame this code hasn't changed in the last 11 years.

### Debugging

I used a debugger on the code given in the Devise Wiki: ([Source](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-OmniAuth-inside-localized-scope))

```rb
devise_for :users, only: :omniauth_callbacks, controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: 'auth/oauth_callbacks' }

scope '(:locale)' do
  devise_for :users, skip: :omniauth_callbacks, 
    controllers: { passwords: 'auth/passwords', registrations: 'auth/registrations' }
end
```

After the first `devise_for` call the controller configuration in the Devise mappings looked like this:

```
Devise.mappings.first[1].controllers = Hash (1 element)
 :omniauth_callbacks => "auth/oauth_callbacks"
```

After the second call:

```
Devise.mappings.first[1].controllers = Hash (5 elements)
 :passwords => "auth/passwords"
 :registrations => "auth/registrations"
 :sessions => "devise/sessions"
 :confirmations => "devise/confirmations"
 :unlocks => "devise/unlocks"
```

As you can see, the original controller configuration is gone.

### Devise Wiki, Issues

The following Wiki articles, issues and comments say that using multiple `devise_for` calls is in fact working:

- https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-OmniAuth-inside-localized-scope
- https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/issues/3651#issue-90422948
- https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/pull/2227#issuecomment-31399288

I'm seriously doubting myself here: On one hand this is the official way to go when using OmniAuth with dynamic segments, accompanied by various confirmations by other users. On the other hand it's obvious (imho) that this just cannot work.

Am I missing something here?

**EDIT:**

After further investigation I'm more and more sure this never actually worked in Devise. The reason nobody noticed is that when accessing a missing controller configuration, Devise auto-generates a default configuration (**re**-generates in this case)

In `Devise::Mapping#default_controllers`: ([Source](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/5d5636f03ac19e8188d99c044d4b5e90124313af/lib/devise/mapping.rb#L131))

```rb
def default_controllers(options)
  mod = options[:module] || "devise"
  @controllers = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = "#{mod}/#{k}" }  # <----------- DEFAULT
  @controllers.merge!(options[:controllers]) if options[:controllers]
  @controllers.each { |k,v| @controllers[k] = v.to_s }
end
```

So in case someone only wants to just pull up the routes omniauth module out of the dynamic route segment, the documented way actually does work, but this is more or less by chance. The first call to `devise_for` still cannot be omitted because it generates routes and helper methods (which are maintained by Rails and maintained over multiple calls). But the `controllers: ...` option could just as well be omitted and the auto-generated configuration would kick in.

So if you want the integrated omniauth controller of Devise the official solution kinda works, if you actually need a different controller, it doesn't.

**EDIT 2:**

Adding this line after the second `devise_for` call restores the controller configuration. With it the recommended solution actually works:

```rb
Devise.mappings[:user].controllers[:omniauth_callbacks] = 'users/omniauth_callbacks'
```

I added an issue to the Devise issue tracker, this really seems to be a bug or at least an unexpected edge case. ([Issue](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/issues/5375))